# Android: Start Activity within Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am new to android development. Right now I have tabs in my action bar. I have created  classes for those fragments. My first class has only one button currently. I'll add more later. I try to start an activity within this class when you click a button, but it won't work...It just crashes Here's the code:

```
package com.cydeon.plasmamodz;

import com.cydeon.plasmamodz.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

  public class ThemeFragment extends Fragment {

   @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.theme_frag,
            container, false);
    Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Themes.class);
            getActivity().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return view;
}}
```

I did define the themes class in the manifest. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, and could really use some help. As I said, I'm only 15 and new to this.

Comment: "It just crashes". Do you get any errors? If so please add the exact error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code is fine. I began to make the Themes class within my ThemeFragment class, but then made it a new class, and forgot to delete it. Everything works fine now.