# Add a onitemclick listner for list view in sliding menu fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview, android-fragments

I have a sliding menu with fragment and list view in my Android application. I want to add on item click listener for this fragment.
Here is the code I used for the fragment :

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class LeftMenuFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.leftmenu, container, false);
  }
}
```

This is the code of the menu lay out :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#2C323F" >

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp" 
    android:background="@drawable/blue_bg">
</TableLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/searchView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
    android:entries="@array/menu_array">
</ListView>
```

Here the `menu_array` is a string resource. I want to add onitem click listner for the list view in Fragment. How to do this  This is complicated for me.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this in your onCreateView :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.leftmenu, container, false);
    ListView list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id. listView1);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
        // do things with the clicked item
    }
    });
    return view;
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can keep a reference to your list and set the OnItemClickListener in the onActivityCreated of your Fragment, if the onItemClick method needs anything from your Activity to work correctly.

I hope this helps ;)

Comment: Your answer is exactly what I needed, but one thing I want to know,, how can I start new activity in onItemClick ? 
thank you very much!

Comment: You can create a new `Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyNextActivity.class` and then `startActivity(i);`

Comment: Ok found it here :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048118/android-start-activity-within-fragment

Comment: I had forgotten a cast to ListView in my original response, it's corrected now, sorry about that, wrote the code on the fly ;)